# How do I properly loop through the subplots of a matplotlib figure to show the final y-axis value of each line?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, matplotlib, yaxis

I currently have a matplotlib figure with 16 subplots, 4 columns and 4 rows. I have the following code produced that loops through each subplot and plots different data on each of the 16 subplots:

```
fac_list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten , eleven, twelve, 
thirteen, fourteen, fifteen, sixteen]
color = ['blue','red']

ds_i = 0
for row in range(0,subplot_shape[0]):
    for col in range(0,subplot_shape[1]):
        fac = fac_list[ds_i]
            plot('total', 
                    currentname=fac,
                    subplot_index=(row,col),
                    linestyle='-',
                    marker='.',
                    label='NEW',
                    color=color[0])
            leg2 = axes[row][col].legend(loc='upper left',bbox_to_anchor=(-0.10, 1.04), prop={'size':8},
                frameon=False, markerscale=0, handlelength=0)
            for line, text in zip(leg2.get_lines(), leg2.get_texts()):
                text.set_color(line.get_color())
            #axes[row][col].text(1.1,new_obj['total'].values[-1],new_obj['total'].values[-1],horizontalalignment='center',fontsize=5, rotation=45,
                #transform=axes[row][col].transAxes, color=color[0])
        ds_i += 1
```

Currently, I've got it so the commented out lines show the final y-axis value of only the last item in fac_list (sixteen), but this value shows up on every subplot in my figure, not just the last subplot (which is the subplot it should be showing up under). How do I loop through the subplots correctly so that the final y-axis value for each item in fac_list shows up in each corresponding subplot (one in fac_list shows up on subplot (0,0), two in fac_list shows up on subplot (0,1), etc.)? Nothing I've tried has worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the line and bring it at the same indentation level as the for loop for the column

```
for row in range(0,subplot_shape[0]):
    for col in range(0,subplot_shape[1]):
    ...
    ...

        for line, text in zip(leg2.get_lines(), leg2.get_texts()):
            text.set_color(line.get_color())

# Place the following line as it is in this answer
    axes[row][col].text(1.1,new_obj['total'].values[-1],new_obj['total'].values[-1],
                        horizontalalignment='center',fontsize=5, rotation=45,
                        transform=axes[row][col].transAxes, color=color[0])
```

Comment: hmm..it seems to be giving me an unexpected indent error when I do that. I'll keep messing with it and see if I can get it to work. Thanks for your help!